# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in commentary Laravel system

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the Username of author to display that near comments which they wrote, when displaying a comments on page. I've got an error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

---

Controller:

```
public function index(Site $site)
    {

        $comments=Comments::where('siteId', $site->id)->get();
        return view('admin.comments.show', compact('comments'));
    }
```

View:

```
    @foreach($comments as $comment)

{{$comment->user->name}}

    @endforeach
```

User model:

```
public function comments()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
  }
```

Comment model:

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I want to use relations. Thank you for help! :)

Comment: In your comment model, is the user relationship really called comments?

Comment: Yes @Phiter and that was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the relationship in the `Comment` model to this:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

In user model:

```
public function comments()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Comment::class); // change Comments to Comment here
  }
```

In Comment model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```